# How can i send data into input that doesn't have name using jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to send data into search form in a website using jsoup.
but this input doesn't have a name 
can anyone help me
the website looks like this

I tried using the form name but it doesn't work

```
<form name="f">
<input id="y" autocomplete="off">
....
<input>
<select id="s" style="">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>
</form>
```

here i want to send data to the input with the id y 
and get some result if the data is sent 
but the result is empty

Comment: Try to fill the form using your browser and intercept the request using developer tools > network tool.
You'll see all parameters that are sent to the server when the form is submitted! Use these parameter in the jsoup request et voilà! :D

Comment: It would be easier to explain having the URL of this page.

Comment: i used the tool but still not working. this is the url :  https://manganelo.com/home  i want to get the result of the search after sending the search word @KrystianG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a name probably because there's some javascript code to get the value and then send request.
According to Roberto's advice it's really easily visible in browser's debugger in Network tab and you can see it's sent as a `searchword` parameter:

[image]

The next problem you're going to have is that the response comes as a JSON and you can't parse it with Jsoup. You will have to get it with `.ignoreContentType(true)` and then use some JSON parsing library. 
But there seems to be another way. Just try to GET the URL directly with a search phrase like: https://manganelo.com/search/killua_san
The response already contains search results in HTML code so Jsoup will be able to parse it.